# How to set two divs on a single line - error with my code?

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```css
.icon_live{
            background-color: #fe3860;
            width: 100px;
            height: 25px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            display: grid;
            place-items: center;
        }
        .anim_live{
            background-color: #aeaeae;
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
        .icon_live,.anim_live{
            display: inline;
        }
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="icon_live"><text style="margin-bottom: 2px;color: white;"><b>LIVE</b></text>
</div><span id="anim_live"></span>
```

What it looks like (please ignore black line on left):

[image: Screenshot]

I would like the grey circle to be on the right of `LIVE`

**ALSO**

Does anyone know how I can get the grey circle to disappear and reappear every 1 second?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `id` in html and `class` selector in css for `anim_live`. Make both element `display:inline-block` and use css animation for grey dot. Learn more about css animations https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp.

```css
.icon_live{
            background-color: #fe3860;
            width: 100px;
            height: 25px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            display: grid;
            place-items: center;
        }
        .anim_live{
            background-color: #aeaeae;
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            animation: animateGreyDot 1s linear infinite;
        }
        .icon_live,.anim_live{
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        @keyframes animateGreyDot{
          from {opacity: 1}
          to{opacity: 0}
        }
```

```html
<div class="icon_live"><text style="margin-bottom: 2px;color: white;"><b>LIVE</b></text>
</div><span class="anim_live"></span>
```